# Lengthen Variables

Tags: bash, scripts

I print data to a form in a console and use `tput cup` the print it on the same position. This way I can create a sort of form with a small discription of each value. but if you run

```
var=12
tput cup 2 4; echo "$var"
```

after

```
var=9999
tput cup 2 4; echo "$var"
```

you get

```
usr@node: /dir> 1299
```

is there a beter wat to solve this problem then

```
var=9999
tput cup 2 4; echo "$var"

tput cup 2 4; echo "          "

var=12
tput cup 2 4; echo "$var"
```

maybe adding spaces to the end of each varible so it is always the same amount of characters or something?

Comment: "tput 2 4;" errors out on me with "tput: unknown terminfo capability" What is that suppose to do? And I would use "echo -e" so you can use tabs (\t).

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. As @Rinzwind comments, it may be useful to know what is `tput` supposed to do here. [edit] your post to make explicit what is your ultimate goal.

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my screen. I get 9999, no distortions there

Comment: @Serg If the value 12 comes first you're right. but if you get a shorter value (12 for example) to print on that same spot where priviously was printed 9999, you get the distortions

Comment: @Roffel ah, I see what you mean. Well, you could continuously clear the whole screen, unless you need the other areas of the screen to remain uncleared

Comment: @Serg by clearing the whole screen, I lose data as I won't get everything al the time unfortunatly

Comment: @Roffel so last small question before I intend posting an answer: how large are numbers ? max 4 digits ? or more? Also, how much space you can spare on that line ?

Comment: @Serg Some numbers can take up to 10 digits, integers and decimals

Comment: Answer posted, please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `echo` with `printf "%10.0" $var`

What this does is tells printf to print a line of width 10 spaces, treat the `$var` as floating point, but because we have .0 there , parts after decimal dot aren't printed. Try this:

`var=9999; tput cup 2 4; printf  "%10.0f" $var; sleep 2; var=12; tput cup 2 4; printf  "%10.0f" $var;`

Comment: If you like this solution, please leave an upvote. If this answer solves the problem, please check the grey checkmark next to the upvote /downvote arrows to accept the answer as the proper solution. Thank you !

Comment: this is almost what I need. just 2 minor details. Is it possible to print te number first, and the spaces after? now it prints the spaces first, and the numbers later.
and is there a way to make this work with string as wel? the numbers are not always availeble, so it ill give me "-", "N/A" or something else. Or should I fix this with by chicking if it's number before printing it?

Comment: @Roffel Yes, padding on the right is possible. Just replace `"%10.0f"` with `"%-10.0f"` (  minus sign between % and 10).  As for words, `printf ` will show error if you try to stick a word where `%f` expects a number. But that error might overwrite your data in other parts of screen. So i suggest checking before printing